# what is "Defining A Layout On A Controller" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

what is "Defining A Layout On A Controller" in Laravel? For example this code :

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
```

What does this mean?:

```
$this->layout->content
```

I have read the documentation but I didn't understand it.

Comment: `"Defining A Layout On A Controller"` means you are defining it in controller ant not in views. in blade views, you can define a layout by `@extends('layout')`....

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel` gives us two different ways to use a `Layout`, in the `Controller` and also in the `View` by extending the `master/main` layout. So, defining a layout in the controller looks like this:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
    // The master layout in the layouts folder
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function showProfile()
    {
        // Set the content to the master layout to display
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
    }
}
```

So, a layout is a `template` where the content generated by a view will be presented within that layout. On the other hand, you can use a `layout` directly from the view and in this case you don't need to define a layout in the controller. A view will extend the master layout like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('sidebar')
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop
```

The master layout may look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Read more on the [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates).

Comment: _offtopic:_ you have a mail on your blog Alpha.

Comment: thank you very much, but the @section('sidebar') why you didn't use @yield instead